# How can I prevent Meta from opening up KDE Plasma's launcher?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, plasma, kde5, plasma5

When I press <kbd>Meta</kbd>, KDE Plasma's Application Launcher (Kickoff) opens. This occurs whether I tap the key, or hold it down for a long time. How can I prevent this from occurring?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As implied [here](https://github.com/hanschen/ksuperkey), edit `~/.config/kwinrc`, adding the following lines to the bottom.

```
[ModifierOnlyShortcuts]
Meta=
```

Then restart kwin with `kwin_x11 --replace & disown`.